# Foundation - Showing Conditional Form Items

Tags: forms, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm a bit new to Foundation, working on doing a responsive redesign for an existing application form. Several of the questions in this form are of the type where you answer a fairly general question, then depending on your selection, you might need to enter more information. Here's a very basic example:

```
<fieldset class="row columns">
    <legend>Do you like ice cream?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="Yes">Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="icecream" value="No">No</label>
</fieldset>

<div id="flavor" class="row columns hide">
  <label>What flavor?
    <input type="text" name="flavor">
  </label>
</div>
```

What I need to do is only show the #flavor div if the user selects the Yes option, and hide it by default or if the user selects No. I can accomplish this easily with some added jQuery, but I feel like I'm missing a native way to handle this in Foundation. I've tried using Toggler, but it toggles the state instead of letting me specify the state of #flavor for each radio input. I've tried Reveal, but it seems designed only for modals.

I've searched the docs, but can't seem to find any other built-in methods for showing/hiding elements dynamically. Am I missing something?

[I've set this up in CodePen if it helps.](https://codepen.io/davesarley/pen/oeevrB) It has the jQuery method for making it function to demonstrate what I'm trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin within Foundation that does exactly what you're looking for here - your jQuery solution seems reasonable, though I'd trigger it based on a `change` rather than a click to handle other ways of triggering besides click (ie if someone selects using keyboard navigation).

There *is* a `toggle-focus` mechanism within Foundation for toggling when e.g. an input is focused, but no `toggle-selected`. This seems like a pretty reasonable request, if you want to [file an issue around it on the Foundation github repo](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/new) I suspect someone would build it. Or if you were excited to build it yourself, you could submit a pull request with the implementation and we'd work with you to get it in. If you want to go down this road, take a look at how the `toggle-focus` works here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.util.triggers.js#L94

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll definitely look at either filing it as a suggestion or working on an implementation for submission.